# Typescript: How to get the stacktrace from an error objecgt

Tags: typescript

Using Typescript, how do I get just the stacktrace from the error?

For example look at this sample code:

```
} catch (err: any) {
    console.log(err.message);
    console.log(err.stackTrace);
    console.log(err.stack);
    console.log(err);
}
```

Take a look at these results from the above code:

[image]

What method or property do I use to get only the 3 lines of the stacktrace?

```
1) err.message:  provides he error message as expected. 
2) err.stackTrace: provides and object but I'm not sure exactly what. 
3) err.stack: and "err" return exactly the same thing - everything.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the stack trace we can use the `stack` property of the `Error` instance as documented on [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack).

Lets store the result of following operations in a variable called `stack`. Lets utilise the new line character in the stack to separate the lines into array elements. After that we can `slice()` the array to ignore first index which is the **error message** and take the next 3 elements to include the 3 lines as required, since we are using `slice(1, 4)` we are guaranteed at most 3 lines of the stack trace. After that we can join these array elements into string using `join("\n")` to join with new line character.

The code goes as the following:

```
const stack = err.stack.split("\n").slice(1, 4).join("\n");
console.log(stack); // to view the result
```